# Why 0 is taken as even number in one case and not in other case..Python

Tags: python, list, filter

I have two different codes (in python) in which 0 is return as even number in one and in another 0 is not return as a even number
Example 1:

```
nums=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def check_even(num):
    if num%2==0:
      return num

newlist=list(filter(check_even,nums))#function inside
print(newlist)
```

Result=[2,4,6,8,10]

Example 2:

```
nums=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def check_even(num):
      return num%2==0

newlist=list(filter(check_even,nums))#function inside
print(newlist)
```

Result:[0,2,4,6,8,10]
I just want to know the reason or the process behind two different output..

Comment: You return the number in the first function and `0` is "falsy", in the other you return `True` when you pass `0`

Answer (score 1):

Lets give the `check_even` methods different names and test what they return:

```
def check_even_1(num):
    if num%2==0:
      return num

def check_even_2(num):
      return num%2==0

nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

[check_even1(n) for n in nums]
# [0, None, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8, None, 10]

[check_even2(n) for n in nums]
# [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

What you can see is that `check_even_1` returns the even values while `check_even_2` returns `True` for even numbers and `False` for odd.

Later you try to apply the `filter` method which expects the filter method to return booleans so it actually converts the outputs to bools. By doing so '0' and `Null` are  turned into `False`, and other numbers to `True`:

```
[bool(check_even1(n)) for n in nums]
# [False, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

Now the '0' value turned into `False` and the `filter` method thinks that it should be filtered out.

Because of this, when using the `filter` method, make sure that your filtering method returns booleans.